# pointer events won't toggle through javascipt?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to fade in and out a drop down menu on click. Currently using CSS animation to fade it out in and using JS to toggle the class for the animation. I have created a variable in js to check if the object contains the fade class - if the class opacity of element is 0, I want the pointer events of the element to be set to none and set to all if the element if the element is visible, however the variable doesn't update and remains false. I am new to javascript.

HTML

```
<button class="mobile__more">+</button>
<div class="mobile__process-nav">
  <a href="#show" data-tab-target="#show" class="mobile__tab">Show</a>
  <a href="#about" data-tab-target="#about" class="mobile__tab">About</a>
   <a href="#researchFilm" data-tab-target="#researchFilm" class="mobile__tab">Research Film</a>
   <a href="#stills" data-tab-target="#stills" class="mobile__tab">Stills</a>
   <a href="#lookbook" data-tab-target="#lookbook" class="mobile__tab">Lookbook</a>
</div>
```

css

```
.mobile__process-nav {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   height: 30vh;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.mobile__process-nav.fade {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

JS

```
const morebtn = document.querySelector('.mobile__nav');
const processMenu = document.querySelector('.mobile__process-nav');
if (window.matchMedia("(max-device-width: 850px)").matches) {

let menuOpen = processMenu.classList.contains('fade');

   morebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      processMenu.classList.toggle('fade');
      if (!menuOpen) {
         console.log(menuOpen);
         processMenu.style.pointerEvents = "none";
      } else {
         console.log(menuOpen);
         processMenu.style.pointerEvents = "all";
      }
})
}
```

Comment: You need to check whether the element has that class, _after_ you toggled the class. Right now, you are only checking when your script initializes, so `menuOpen` will _keep_ whatever the value was at this point.

Comment: should i be add the toggle inside the if statement?

Comment: @LaiqaMohid move `let menuOpen = processMenu.classList.contains('fade');` to the callback, so after line: `morebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {`

Comment: this solved the problem thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the variable `menuOpen` inside click callback